# Unfortunately WhatsApp has stopped.

Tags: applications, whatsapp-messenger, lg

So, yeah. The infamous error. I know several ways of "fix" this. But, Factory reset, erase cache, erase data has not work. When I'm trying to put my phone number for confirmation in the app, it closes. I'm not sure what's happening, any ideas?

My phone is and LG L35.

Comment: [tag:logcat] may help you a bit. See http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1726238 if you're new to logcat.

Comment: is this happening after you took update of WhatsApp app? or...?

Comment: Install old version apk over the new one(i.e don't uninstall new one, try to install an old version apk on top of the newinstalled one) I read somewhere (MIUI forum) that overriding on new version solved the issue for some.

Comment: @AADTechnical No, no update at all. Just started to happen a few weeks before.

Comment: @Manubhargav Oh, I thought that was not possible anymore, will try that too.